# Having troubles to write list in a new row every time during while loop with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, openpyxl

I'm encountering problems inserting the list values into a new row every time the code loops.
In a few words, I need the code every, it loops to write the values from `lst` into a separate row each time.
I have done an extensive research to try to understand how this works and found plenty of examples but unfortunately, I couldn't make the code work following those examples.

This is the code:

```
    max_value = 5
    lst = []

    while True:
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        num = (max_value)
        for n in range(num):
            weight = float(input('Weight: '))
            lst.append(weight)
        ws.append(lst)

        if n+1 == max_value:
            wb.save(filename='path')
```

I have tried to add `ws.insert_rows(idx=2, amount=1)` just after the line `ws.append(lst)` like this:

```
    ...

    ws.insert_rows(idx=2, amount=1)
    ws.append(lst)

    if n+1 == max_value:
        wb.save(filename='path')
```

but it doesn't do anything because I suppose it needs something that tells the code to write the next values in that row.
I have also tried something like this:

```
    ...
        
    next_avail_row = len(list(ws.rows))
    ws.append(lst)

    if n+1 == max_value
        wb.save(filename='path')
```

But here as well I'm not sure how to tell the code after it finds `next_avail_row = len(list(ws.rows))` to write in that row.

Thoughts?

EDIT:

At the moment if I enter at the prompt for instance:
1,2,3,4,5

it outputs:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c13CG.png]

if I continue inputting numbers for instance:
7,6,5,4,3

it outputs:

[image: ![https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ2mN.png]

and so forth, what I expect to be is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rSIl.png]

in a few words, every time the function gets called it writes in the same file but one row below. I hope it is a clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

First, in your `while` loop. Every time that it loops through it is calling `wb = Worbook()` and eventually `wb.save(filename='path')`. This is creating a new excel worksheet every time. Assuming that in your `wb.save()` call that the filename is the same each time, every time you call save on the new workbook it will overwrite the previously made workbook with that same file name.

Next, your list that contains the `weight` values that you have being input. You aren't clearing the list so each time you add something to it in the loop the list will just keep expanding.

Also the line `num = (max_value)` doesn't really do anything, and you also need to have some kind of condition to break out of your `while` loop. Using `while True` will keep the loop going forever unless you break out of it at some point.

Here is some code that should do this the way that you want it to:

```
max_value = 5

line_count = 0

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
white True:
   lst = []
   for n in range(max_value):
      weight = float(input('Weight: '))
      lst.append(weight)
   ws.append(lst)

   line_count += 1
   # an example condition to break out of the loop
   if line_count >= 5:
      break
   
wb.save(filename='path')
```

Here, your `Workbook` object is only being created and saved once so it isn't opening a new one each time and overwriting the previous `Workbook`. The list `lst` is being emptied each time through the loop so that your lines will only be as long as the value in `max_value`. I also added in an example way of breaking out of your `while True:` loop. The way I set it is that once there have been 5 lines that you have added to the workbook, it will break out of the loop. You can create any condition you want to break out of the loop, this is just for example purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although I don't understand how this code is going to make the value jump one row every time it loops. Could you kindly explain to me what I am missing here?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your original question. If you could edit your question to give an example of the output you are trying to get that would help.

Comment: That is ok not a problem I had trouble describing what I was looking to achieve, my bad. I have edited the post with some images and I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I remade my answer with to work with your changes. Please take a look and let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: thank you very much for fixing this, I would like to kindly ask if you could explain to me how by adding  line_count += 1 it changes row? I just would like to know if in the future I would like to implement the code by adding empty rows or maybe columns and I guess this could be helpful. I also am not able to edit your answer you just need to indent the last line otherwise it doesn't save, this is in case someone will look at the code

Comment: You are welcome. The `line_count` variable has no effect on what row each list is being placed in, it is the example condition on which I set up to break out of the `while True` loop. Otherwise the loop would keep going forever. The call to `ws.append()` places the row on the next line of the worksheet regardless of what line it is.

Comment: While you can add the save call in the loop, you do not need to as long as you are allowing the loop to finish fully. In the example I set up it will loop 5 times and then when it is finished it will save the entire thing, rather than saving every time the loop runs.

Comment: Thanks Nathan this explains very well what the code does, I'll playing around a little bit more to see what I can improve!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your program.